# Set the fore ground of a swing component by using color code

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way to set the fore ground of for example a label directly by color code rather than the predefined colors that java provides.

For instance :

```
instead of:
SomeLabel.setForeground(Color.Red); 
We do:
SomeLabel.setForeground("240,240,240");
```

I'm asking this question because I'm setting label colors of the required fields to red when the user skips them, so when I wanna reset their color I can't find the color that I've defined within the predefined colors that java provides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `new Color(240, 240, 240)`

Take a look at [`javax.swing.Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) for more details

You can also reset the labels back to their look and feel defaults using `UIManager.getColor("Label.foreground");` on most look and feels, for example

Comment: One thing MadProgrammer, I just note that its is java.awt.Color which works very well, but asking this out of curiosity, is there also a javax.swing.Color? I searched by couldn't find it.

Comment: @FlowFlowOverFlow No, Swing borrows heavily from AWT, actually makes life simpler, as you don't need to keep wondering if you have the right class or not...it can also be a little frustrating as well (`Image`, `ImageIcon`, `Icon`, `BufferedImage`...:P)

Answer (score 3):

```
SomeLabel.setForeground(new Color(240,240,240));
```

You can use Color class of java

You can also add Alpha etc. Refer to the Color constructor below

```
 Color(ColorSpace cspace, float[] components, float alpha)
Creates a color in the specified ColorSpace with the color components specified in the float array and the specified alpha.

Color(float r, float g, float b)
Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified red, green, and blue values in the range (0.0 - 1.0).

Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)
Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0.0 - 1.0).

Color(int rgb)
Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified combined RGB value consisting of the red component in bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.

Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)
Creates an sRGB color with the specified combined RGBA value consisting of the alpha component in bits 24-31, the red component in bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.

Color(int r, int g, int b)
Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified red, green, and blue values in the range (0 - 255).

Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)
Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0 - 255).
```